# Resolving "Unhandled rejection TypeError: jquery_1.default is not a function"

Tags: jquery, typescript, asp.net-core, aurelia

I am trying to call use jQuery in my Aurelia attached function. Whenever the jQuery command runs, I get this error:

Unhandled rejection TypeError: jquery_1.default is not a function.

Here is my app.ts code:

```
    import {Redirect, NavigationInstruction, RouterConfiguration} from 'aurelia-router';
    import 'semantic';
    import $ from 'jquery';

    export class App {
      configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration): void {
        config.title = 'TrackRack';
        config.options.hashChange = false;
        config.options.root = '/';
        config.map([
          { route: ['home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'views/home' },
          { route: '', name: 'home2', moduleId: 'views/home'}
        ]);
      }
      attached() {
          $('.nav_menu').visibility({
            type: 'fixed'
          });
      }
    }
```

Here is my config:

```
            {
                "name": "jquery",
                "path": "../node_modules/jquery/dist",
                "main": "jquery.js"
                },
                {
                "name": "semantic",
                "path": "../node_modules/semantic-ui/dist",
                "main": "semantic.js",
                "resources": [
                    "semantic.min.css"
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do in your aurelia.json is

`"jquery"`

No need to go more complicated than that for jQuery.

Also, please note that you can use the `ref` custom attribute in your view to get a reference to an element in your view. You can this pass this reference to jQuery instead of doing a search for the element.

**app.html**

```
<template>
  ...
  <nav ref="navMenu">
    ...
  </nav>
  ...
</template>
```

**app.ts**

```
 $(this.navMenu)).visibility({
     type: 'fixed'
 });
```

Comment: In addition to this, I had to change my import to this for everything to function correctly ==> import * as $ from 'jquery'